# eliminate loop from rowwise subseting of data

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, vectorization

I have two data sets - TEST end TRAIN. TEST is a subset of TRAIN. By using the columns "prod" and "clnt" I need to find all rows in TRAIN which corresponds to TEST (it is one to multiple correspondence). Then I make a temporal analysis of the respective values of the column "order" of TEST (first column "week" is the time).

So I take the first row of TRAIN, I compare all rows of TEST whether some of them contain the same combination of numbers of "prod" and "clnt" and record the respective values of "order" in TS. Usually I have zero to about ten values in TS per row of TRAIN. Then I do some calculations on TS (in this artificial case just mean(TS)) and record the result as well as the "Id" of the row of TEST in a data set Subm.

The algorithm works, but because I have millions of rows in TRAIN and TEST, I need it as fast as possible and especially to get rid of the loop, which is the slowest part. Probably I messed up with the data.frame declaration/usage also, but I am not sure.

```
set.seed(42)
NumObsTrain=100000 # this can be as much as 70 000 000
NumObsTest=10000 # this can be as much as 6 000 000

#create the TRAIN data set
train1=floor(runif(NumObsTrain, min=0, max=NumObsTrain+1))
train1=matrix(train1,ncol = 2)
train=cbind(8,train1) #week
train=rbind(train,cbind(9,train1)) #week
train=cbind(train,runif(NumObsTrain,min=1,max=10)) #order
train=cbind(c(1:nrow(train)),train)# id number of each row
colnames(train)=c("id","week","prod","clnt","order")
train=as.data.frame(train)
train=train[sample(nrow(train)),] # reflush the rows of train

# Create the TEST dataset
test=train[1:NumObsTest,]
test[,"week"][1:{NumObsTest/2}]=10
test[,"week"][{(NumObsTest/2)+1}:NumObsTest]=11

TS=numeric(length = 10)
id=c(1:NumObsTest*2)
order=c(1:NumObsTest*2)
Subm=data.frame(id,order)
ptm <- proc.time()

# This is the loop
for (i in 1:NumObsTest){
   Subm$id[i]=test$id[i]
   TS=train$order[train$clnt==test$clnt[i]&train$prod==test$prod[i]]
   Subm$order[i]=mean(TS)
}
proc.time() - ptm
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your explanation is a little bit unclear. I ran your code, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking at. Why does `TS` only have two values at the end? (At least when I tried it)

From the description in the beginning, seems like you want all rows of TRAIN which also appear in TEST, considering only the `prod` and `clnt` columns. If that's the case, using `dplyr::semi_join(train, test, by = c("prod", "clnt"))` will give you that part of the answer.

Comment: @LuisUsie, This is artificial example and it works as supposed to be. It is normal to have just two values in TS. You are correct that I want all rows of TRAIN ,appearing in TEST, cons. "prod" and "clnt" The only problem is the low speed caused by the using of the loop at the end. I know that some vectorization is necessary, but I am still newby in R. So I will try the advice about dplyr.

Comment: @sebastianmm I tryed to provide working example. If you just run the script it generates the all data necessary.

Comment: @LuisUsier Yes, now it partly serves the purpose. Now I need to extract the equal rows (considering the equal couples `"prod"&"clnt"`) from the result of the `dlpyr` operation, and to do some math over the last column, e.g. `mean("order")`. In this (artificial) example we have two repetitions per row. In the general case I don't know how many are the repetitions - they are different among the rows, somewhere between 0 and 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will create a data.frame with all `(prod, clnt)` and `order` combinations, then group them by `prod` and `clnt`, then take the mean of the order of each group. The final result is missing the `id`, and for some reason you have more data in your final data.frame, which I cannot figure out why. But the `order` results are correct.

```
newtrain <- train[, 3:5]
newtest <- test[, c(1, 3:4)]
x <- dplyr::inner_join(newtest, newtrain)
y <- dplyr::group_by(x, prod, clnt)
z <- dplyr::summarise(y, mean(order))
```